# Trying to convert a simple C program into an AWK program

Tags: scripts, awk

Hey guys a couple of weeks ago I wrote a C program that prompts the user for the name of a text file and then prompts the user for a word. The program then outputs the input text file with numbers to the left of the text and outputs the number of times the word appears in the text file. It also outputs the matching line numbers in which the words are located.

Here is a sample of it in action:

```
Enter the name of a text file: **bond.txt**
Enter the pattern to search for: Bond
File contents:
1) Secret agent Bond had been warned not to tangle with Goldfinger.
2) But the super-criminal's latest obsession was too strong, too dangerous.
3) He had to be stopped.
4) Goldfinger was determined to take possession of half the supply of
5) mined gold in the world--to rob Fort Knox!
6) For this incredible venture he had enlisted the aid of the top
7) criminals in the U.S.A, including a bevy of beautiful thieves from the
8) Bronx. And it would take all of Bond's unique talents to make it fail--
9) as fail it must.
There is a match on line 1
There is a match on line 8
'Bond' appeared 2 times in the file bond.txt.
```

Currently I am trying to practice awk programming by repeating the program I did in C but using awk.

Here is what I can muster up so far:

```
BEGIN{
    printf("Enter filename : ")
    getline file < "-"
    while((getline < file)) {
        {print "File Contents:"}
        {printf("%5d) %s\n", NR,$0)}
    }
}
```

This is in no way complete but what would be the best way that can allow me to parse the text file line by line to search for the word entered by the user. Any tips, tricks? Thank you.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has been cross-posted: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/243905/trying-to-convert-a-simple-c-program-into-an-awk-program

Answer (score 1):

With `awk` it's much better to provide filename as command-line argument, if it's something simple as searching for matches and which lines contain the match. In pure awk this would be something like this

```
awk '/searchTerm/ {print "Match on " NR }' inputFile.txt
```

But sure enough, your program can be slightly edited and turned into AWK script to do the same job, however with more lines of code. The only small quirk is that one has to press Ctrl+D to stop the while loop once file is done reading.

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f 

BEGIN{
    printf("What do we search for:")
    getline searchTerm
    printf("Enter filename : ")
    getline file < "-"
    print "File Contents:"

    while((getline < file)) {       
        x++
        printf("%d) %s\n",x,$0)
        if ($0 ~ searchTerm)  {i++;array[i] = x}
    } 
    #  end while statement
}

END{
    print "There were "i" matches on lines:"
    for (j=1;j<=i;j++) printf array[j]" ";
}
```

Bellow you will find the demo. Compare the "translated" code above, with pure AWK:

```
xieerqi:$ ./testAwk.awk

What do we search for:wlan0
Enter filename : inputFile.txt
File Contents:
1) [33330.084088] wlan0: associate with 00:24:37:10:9c:10 (try 1/3)
2) [33330.086392] wlan0: RX AssocResp from 00:24:37:10:9c:10 (capab=0x411 status=0 aid=1)
3) [33330.086432] wlan0: associated
4) [40272.298739] audit: type=1400 audit(1447859037.270:65): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" name="/usr/lib/cups/backend/cups-pdf" pid=4082 comm="apparmor_parser"
5) [40272.298753] audit: type=1400 audit(1447859037.270:66): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" name="/usr/sbin/cupsd" pid=4082 comm="apparmor_parser"
6) [40272.299725] audit: type=1400 audit(1447859037.270:67): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" name="/usr/sbin/cupsd" pid=4082 comm="apparmor_parser"
7) [59169.780814] atkbd serio0: Unknown key pressed (translated set 2, code 0xa5 on isa0060/serio0).
8) [59169.780823] atkbd serio0: Use 'setkeycodes e025 <keycode>' to make it known.
9) [59169.783874] atkbd serio0: Unknown key released (translated set 2, code 0xa5 on isa0060/serio0).
10) [59169.783882] atkbd serio0: Use 'setkeycodes e025 <keycode>' to make it known.
There were 3 matches on lines:
1 2 3 

xieerqi:$ awk '/wlan0/{print "Match on " NR }' inputFile.txt
Match on 1
Match on 2
Match on 3
```